# Use meta to match date in WP_Query

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields, wordpress

I have some posts with a custom filed named "event_end_date". I am using Advanced custom fields for that. How can I get the posts which have end_date older than today? I was trying with this, but could not get through.

```
$args = array(
        'cat'       => '6, -33',
        'numberposts'   => -1,
        'post_type'     => 'post',
        'meta_query'    => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'event_end_date',
                'value' => date('y-m-d'),
                'type' => 'DATE',
                'compare' => '>'
            )
        )
    );

//get results
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Here I wanted those posts which have category '6' and does not have category '33'. In the backend, the field - 'event_end_date' has these:

```
Field Type: Date Picker
Display format: 10/11/2014
Return format: 20141110
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you were too look more closely at the data being stored in that actual custom/meta field, you'd find that it's stored as a unix timestamp, not in the return or display format, and because of that, your problem is that your format's don't match up.

You can account for that difference by using the [U code for unix timestamp](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) with `date('U')` instead of `date('y-m-d')`.

In that case your code would look like this:

```
$args = array(
    'cat'       => '6,-33',
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'post',
    'meta_query'    => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'event_end_date',
            'value' => date('U'),
            'type' => 'DATE',
            'compare' => '>'
        )
    )
);

//get results
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the answer. I tried to use date('U'), but did not work. Then I tried with date('Y-m-d', time()), and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Using date('Y-m-d', time()) solved the problem for me.

```
$args = array(
        'category__and'     => array(6),
        'category__not_in'  => array(33),
        'numberposts'       => -1,
        'post_type'         => 'post',
        'post_status'       => 'publish',
        'meta_query'        => array(
            array(
                'key'       => 'event_end_date',
                'value'     => date('Y-m-d', time()),
                'type'      => 'DATE',
                'compare'   => '<'
            )
        )
    );
```